# How to find the binding interface cxf is creating

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf

In my previous question I was told that CXF implements the `javax.xml.ws.BindingProvider` interface.
I've the following WSDL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- May 30, 2006 -->
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:interface="http://www.csapi.org/wsdl/parlayx/sms/send/v2_2/interface" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://www.csapi.org/wsdl/parlayx/sms/send/v2_2/service" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="parlayx_sms_send_service" targetNamespace="http://www.csapi.org/wsdl/parlayx/sms/send/v2_2/service">

   <wsdl:import location="parlayx_sms_send_interface_2_2.wsdl" namespace="http://www.csapi.org/wsdl/parlayx/sms/send/v2_2/interface"/>

   <wsdl:binding name="SendSmsBinding" type="interface:SendSms">
      <soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

      <wsdl:operation name="sendSms">
         <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
               <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
               <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="ServiceException">
               <soap:fault name="ServiceException" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
            <wsdl:fault name="PolicyException">
               <soap:fault name="PolicyException" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
      </wsdl:operation>


      <wsdl:operation name="getSmsDeliveryStatus">
         <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
               <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
               <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="ServiceException">
               <soap:fault name="ServiceException" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
            <wsdl:fault name="PolicyException">
               <soap:fault name="PolicyException" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
      </wsdl:operation>

      <wsdl:operation name="sendSmswithUDH">
        <soap:operation soapAction="" style="document"/>
            <wsdl:input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:input>
            <wsdl:output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:output>
            <wsdl:fault name="ServiceException">
                <soap:fault name="ServiceException" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
            <wsdl:fault name="PolicyException">
                <soap:fault name="PolicyException" use="literal"/>
            </wsdl:fault>
        </wsdl:operation>
   </wsdl:binding>

   <wsdl:service name="SendSmsService">
      <wsdl:port binding="tns:SendSmsBinding" name="SendSms">
         <soap:address location="http://202.126.44.5:9080/SendSmsServices/services/SendSms"/>
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

And the CXF creates `sendSmsService` and interface called `sendSms` but none of them is related to `BindingProvider` interface, and I have to find a way to set to this service user name, password and endpoint.
How can I find the binding interface or is there another way I can do it? Thanks.